# ReferenceError: document is not defined (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, referenceerror

I'm getting the following error:

> "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

This happens while trying to use `document.getElementByID();` when using TypeScript.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the `document` has the potential of being `undefined`.

You'll need to make a guard statement make TypeScript happy like this:

```
if (document) document.getElementById();
```

Now we can be sure that `document` exists before trying to call `getElementById()`, this prevents us from running into issue where `document` is `undefined`.